# CopyFromRecordset in merged cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to move several queries from access database to Excel.
Now, one of those queries must to go at one sheet with merged cells, but this is exporting me wrong.

The code for the query is:

```
Public Sub CreateExcelInfo()
'Set reference to Microsoft Excel Object library
'Set reference to Microsoft ActiveX DataObject 2.x

Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim WB As New Excel.Workbook
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim objRs5 As New ADODB.Recordset
MsgBox ("Este proceso puede tardar unos minutos." & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Por favor abstengase de realizar tareas en el equipo hasta ver el mensaje de finalizado."), vbOKOnly
sFileNameTemplate = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\templates\Informes.xlsm"
sSQL5 = "SELECT [COMENTARIOS ÚLTIMO CIERRE].TipoComentarioInventario, [COMENTARIOS ÚLTIMO CIERRE].Comentario FROM [COMENTARIOS ÚLTIMO CIERRE] " 'Export comments last inventory

With oExcel
.Visible = True
        Set WB = .Workbooks.Add(sFileNameTemplate)
            With WB
                          objRs5.Open sSQL5, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
                          Set rng = .Range("B24")
                          rng.CopyFromRecordset objRs5
                          objRs5.Close
                 End With
            End With

Set objRs5 = Nothing
MsgBox ("!El informe se ha realizado correctamente!"), vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Here's an image with the query and the sheet, now the code is working so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An easy work around is to get the data into excel first and then do formatting (and calculations).

unmerge the cells before the .copyfromrecordset step:

```
Rng.MergeCells = False
```

And then re-merg the cells after

```
Rng.MergeCells = True
```

I would also turn off screen updating so it doesn't look strange to the user.